# Orientation of the Riemann surface corresponding to $w=\sqrt{\lambda-z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I am trying to describe the Riemann surface $F_{\lambda}$ corresponding to the function $w=\sqrt{\lambda-z^2}$ where $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}, \lambda\ne 0$ over $|z|\le 2$.
What I have so far are the following:

Its branch points are $\pm \sqrt{\lambda}$.
By removing a branch cut that connects $-\sqrt{\lambda}$
and $\sqrt{\lambda}$, we obtain a domain $D$ of
$z$ so that two copies of $D$ correspond to
two single-valued functions on $D$
coming from the function $w=\sqrt{\lambda-z^2}$,
where one is negative of the other at the same input $z$.
These two copies of $D$ are open subsets of
$F_{\lambda}$.

[image]

To glue these two copies (drawn as
two squares on the left of
figure),
observe that if we
analytically continued $w$ on one copy of $D$ along
a closed path $\Delta$ that encloses the branch cut,
we still stay in the same $D$. However, if
analytically continued $w$ along
$\nabla$ that passes through the branch cut
(e.g. we let $z$ runs from $-2i$ to $2i$ in the figure),
we will move from one $D$ to another as soon
as we pass the branch cut. Therefore, if we open
up the branch cut into $\Delta$, the two copies
can be glued along $\Delta$ to create a cylinder
as in figure.
Note that in order to match $\nabla$ correctly
and to match the branch points $\pm \sqrt{\lambda}$
when glueing two copies, we first need
to flip one copy of $D$ across the real axis,
as indicated in the figure.

My question is: Say I want to assign an orientation to $F_{\lambda}$ as in the figure, did I get the correct induced orientation on $D$ as in the figure? Or in other words, am I being consistent with my choice of orientation in the figure?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I haven't yet understood your diagrams well enough to answer, but in the hope it helps: We take the standard orientation on each sheet and join the lower edge of the cut in each sheet to the upper edge of the cut in the other sheet.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Yes, this is the reason why I flip one sheet across the real axis, so that when glueing two sheets, lower edge of one matches upper edge of the other. And when I do that, the orientation arrow goes the other way for that sheet.

Comment: On closer look, yes the orientations look correct.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thanks! If you could write this down as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly, the orientation in your diagrams looks correct. In case it's of interest, it's possible to depict the Riemann surface in real three-space by graphing the real parts of the branches of square root. The blue mesh is the sheet where the real part is positive in the upper half-plane and negative in the lower half-plane; the slit from $-\sqrt{\lambda}$ to $\sqrt{\lambda}$ is opened into a literal circle. The gray-shaded surface is the other sheet. The $z$-plane is shown by its real and imaginary axes; vertical projection is the two-sheeted branched cover.

[image: The Riemann surface of a complex circle]